# apex trigger causing error message

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I am working on on trigger which is throwing below error.

"autocount: execution of BeforeInsert

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.autocount: line 40, column 1"

I am getting error at below line

```
ar.AreaCount__c += mapCount.get(ar.id);
```

Can anyone help me out in this issue here if possible please.

Here is my trigger code:

```
trigger autocount on Action_Item__c (before insert) {
if(trigger.isInsert){
            Set<id> strNew = new Set<id>();


            for(Action_Item__c ac:trigger.new)
                    strNew.add(ac.DCS_Build_Cycle__c);

            Map<id,Build_Cycle__c> mapArea = new Map<id,Build_Cycle__c>([Select Name,AreaCount__c ,(select id,DCS_Build_Cycle__c, Action_Item_no__c from Action_Items__r Order By createdDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Build_Cycle__c where id IN: strNew]);
            Map<id,Integer> mapCount = new Map<id,Integer>();


            for(Action_Item__c act:trigger.new){

                    if(mapArea.containsKey(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)){
                            Integer count = 0, arCount=0;
                            if(mapArea.get(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c).Action_Items__r.size()>0)
                                arCount = Integer.valueOf(mapArea.get(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c).Action_Items__r[0].Action_Item_no__c.split('-')[1]);
                            if(mapCount.containsKey(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)){
                                count =   arCount + 1 + mapCount.get(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c);
                                Integer mpcnt=mapCount.get(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)+1;
                                mapCount.put(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c,mpcnt);
                            }
                            else{
                                count = arCount + 1;
                                mapCount.put(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c,1);
                            }

                            if(count<10)
                            act.Action_Item_no__c =  '-00' + count;
                            else if(count>=10 && count<100)
                            act.Action_Item_no__c =  '-0' + count;
                            else if(count>100)
                            act.Action_Item_no__c =  '-' + count;

                    }
            }
            for(Build_Cycle__c ar: mapArea.values()){
                if(mapCount.containsKey(ar.id))
                    ar.AreaCount__c += mapCount.get(ar.id);
            }
    update mapArea.values();
}

 if(trigger.isDelete){
    Set<id> strOld = new Set<id>();
    Map<id,Build_Cycle__c> mapDel = new Map<id,Build_Cycle__c>();
    Map<id,Integer> mapDelCount = new Map<id,Integer>();
    for(Action_Item__c acct : trigger.old)
        strOld.add(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c);
    List<Build_Cycle__c> arr = [select Name,AreaCount__c from Build_Cycle__c where id IN: strOld];
    for(Build_Cycle__c area : arr)
        mapDel.put(area.id, area);
    for(Action_Item__c acct : trigger.old){
            if(mapDel.containsKey(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)){
                    if(mapDelCount.containsKey(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)){
                            Integer countDel=mapDelCount.get(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c)+1;
                            mapDelCount.put(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c,countDel); 
                    }
                    else
                      mapDelCount.put(acct.DCS_Build_Cycle__c,1);      
            }
    }   

    for(Build_Cycle__c ar: mapDel.values()){
        if(mapDelCount.containsKey(ar.id))
            ar.AreaCount__c -= mapDelCount.get(ar.id);
    }
    update mapDel.values();
}

}
```

Comment: Which line is 40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that exception because the value of `AreaCount__c` for the `ar` instance that you are using is `null`.

Below line i.e.

```
ar.AreaCount__c += mapCount.get(ar.id); // which is equal to 
//ar.AreaCount__c = ar.AreaCount__c + mapCount.get(ar.id);
```

As `ar.AreaCount__c` is `null` and as you are referencing a `null` object in your code, it will give you `NullPointerException`

To prevent this exception, you can use ternary operator to check if the value is `null`, before using it.

Replace below line

```
ar.AreaCount__c += mapCount.get(ar.id);
```

with

```
ar.AreaCount__c = (ar.AreaCount__c==null ? 0 : ar.AreaCount__c) + mapCount.get(ar.id);
```

Similarly, you can get the same exception in the below line as well due to the same reason mentioned above

```
ar.AreaCount__c -= mapDelCount.get(ar.id);
```

And in the below line, if `Action_Item_no__c` is `null` and if you try to `split` that, you again can get the same exception.

```
arCount = Integer.valueOf(mapArea.get(act.DCS_Build_Cycle__c).Action_Items__r[0].Action_Item_no__c.split('-')[1]);
```

These are few to be mentioned which you need to handle to prevent such kind of exceptions.